# SQL Server working with unattached databases

Tags: sql-server, visual-foxpro

I am working on a Visual FoxPro application that needs to interface with an unattached SQL Server database. I know the location of the mdf file. It belongs to an application that works with the database. If I attach the mdf to an instance, the application that it belongs to doesn't work.

So, what I basically need to do is temporarily attach the database to an instance, use it and then unattach. All of this under program control.

I have worked out the attach part. If I use a user instance of SQL Server (I'm using 2008 express), I can specify the name of the mdf in the connection string and then it attaches to the user instance. What I have not worked out is how to unattach it under program control. It would be great if the attachment to the instance would go away when I close the connection.

Is this possible? I have googled it and I have not yet been able to find a way to do this.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are in master and have the correct permissions (probably have to be an SA) you can execute this:

```
use master;
go

EXEC MASTER.dbo.sp_detach_db @dbname = N'Name of DB',
@keepfulltextindexfile = N'true'
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

For the VFP application to 'talk' to the SQL Server database tables, you need to create an ODBC Connection to the SQL Server database.

Remember that VFP is a 32-bit application so your ODBC Connection needs to be established within the **%systemdrive%\Windows\SysWoW64** directory and within the **Odbcad32.exe** application.

Alternatively you can use the VFP Commands to set up an 'on-the-fly' connection.
See: https://www.google.com/search?q=32bit+odbc+connection+&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=vfp+connection+string+sql+server

Once you have the Connection established, you can run SQL Queries on the desired data tables to:
1.  Acquire data
2.  Update data
3.  Delete data
4.   etc.

Good Luck